# How can I remove a printer from the .Net print dialog?

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I am working on a Winforms application that allows users to print a few different Reporting Services reports.  Unfortunately, if the user tries to print to PDF using the Adobe PDF printer, it crashes.  We haven't been able to solve this issue, so as a work around we want remove the ability for users to print to the Adobe PDF printer.

Is there any way to programmatically remove the Adobe PDF printer from the list of printers in the print dialog?

Comment: Can you detect the printer name/type after they have chosen it and put up a dialog box at that point to tell them to pick something else?

Comment: We are using the PrintDialog() method on the ReportViewer control.  An exception gets thrown inside the PrintDialog() method when the PDF printer is selected.  We could catch the exception and throw up a dialog, but it would be much nicer to just remove the option all together.

Answer (score 3):

Call this with the printer name before calling PrintDialog().... I think this will solve your issue

```
public bool RemovePrinter(string printerName)
{
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath);
        scope.Connect();
        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("select * from Win32_Printer");
        ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
        ManagementObjectCollection printers = search.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject printer in printers)
        {
            string printerName = printer["Name"].ToString().ToLower();

            if (printerName.Equals(printerName.ToLower()))
            {
                printer.Delete();
                break;
            }
        }                    

        return true;
}
```

Comment: Wait - this looks like it could be uninstalling the printer for the whole system, not just for the program.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure why this is getting down votes.  This is a useful bit of code and not only does it work, it helped me.

Comment: I upvote myself. First thing I found, and it did just what I needed. I'll expand a bit in an alternate answer.

Comment: This worked for me. But can we delete the printer using its type ? I want to delete Microsoft XPS Document writer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from manish gave me what I needed. In my case, I had a virtual printer driver that was being created by a library, and it left orphans like Printer (1), Printer (2), etc. I wanted to delete all of those, so I used a variant of the WMI code above.

```
using System.Management;
//...
var scope = new ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath);
scope.Connect();
var query = new SelectQuery($@"select * from Win32_Printer where Name like '{PrinterDeviceName}%'");
foreach (var o in new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query).Get()) 
    ((ManagementObject) o).Delete();
```

You need a reference to System.Management.