# How to hide or disable a printer in C# printer dialog?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, printdialog

There are 3 printers in the printer list, but is there a way to hide or disable one of them when I call the printdialog? For example, how to disable or hide the printers which names start with "Brother MFC", so that only allows users to select "HP" printers?

```
    PrintDialog printDlg = newPrintDialog();  
    PrintDocument printDoc = newPrintDocument();  
    printDoc.DocumentName = "Print Document";  
    printDlg.Document = printDoc;  
    printDlg.AllowSelection = true;  
    printDlg.AllowSomePages = true;  
    //Call ShowDialog  
    if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) printDoc.Print();
```

Comment: try to see this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272713/how-can-i-remove-a-printer-from-the-net-print-dialog

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a printer from the .Net print dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272713/how-can-i-remove-a-printer-from-the-net-print-dialog)

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it possible to detect a printer is a virtual printer or a phisycal printer?